# What is the simplest way to remove .html with an htaccess file?

Tags: .htaccess

So I have a been trying a lot of different htaccess codings to clean up my url

but am not even able to simply remove .html without something going wrong

Code Im using:
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
    RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ $1.html [L]

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .*[^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301]

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .*[^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ $1.html [L]
```

CODE Im hoping to clean up:

```
 <area shape="poly" coords="3,612,78,557,118,627,5,708"     href="collabwitus.html" />
```

Little new to htaccess and would love some help!

I am doing everything from file manager via hostgator so framing an answer in a more step by step version using file manager would be great!

Answer (score 1):

Put the following code :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.*?/)?(?:index)?(.*?)\.html[\s?/] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1%2 [R=302,L,NE]
```

Comment: What am i supposed to do with the files named .html? if i rename them without.html they only show the code but dont load the actual page... if i dont rename them then they dont work at all...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

Comment: Thanks all i had to do was remove .html from any links on the site

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```